# PHP Contact Form doesn't deliver mails

Tags: php, html, forms

My contact form won't work. The messages aren't sent to the given email address.
The form successes but the emails aren't delivered. The other question has another code using if tags, which won't work for my script.

The html code I used is:

```
 <form class="form" id="form1" action="mail.php" method="post">

  <p class="name">
    <input name="name" type="text" class="validate[required,custom[onlyLetter],length[0,100]] feedback-input" placeholder="NAME" id="name" />
  </p>

  <p class="email">
    <input name="email" type="text" class="validate[required,custom[email]] feedback-input" id="email" placeholder="E-MAIL" />
  </p>

  <p class="text">
    <textarea name="text" class="validate[required,length[6,300]] feedback-input" id="comment" placeholder="WHAT'S UP?"></textarea>
  </p>


  <div class="submit">
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="SEND" id="button-blue"/>
    <div class="ease"></div>
  </div>
</form>
```

The PHP script I use is:

```
<?php

// We create a variable for name value
$name = $_POST['name'];

// We create a variable for email value
$email = $_POST['email'];

// We create a variable for message value
$message = $_POST['text'];

// We provide an e-mail address from which the email is sent
$from = "xyz@adress.com";

// Provide the e-mail address on which you want to receive messages
$to = "xyz@gmx.de";

// Provide the subject of the e-mail
$subject = "Contact form from xyz.com";

// We prepare the message body
$emailbody = "";
$emailbody .= "Message: " . $message . "\n";

// We add UTF-8 to the header of our message
$header = "";
$header .= "From:" . $from . " \n";
$header .= "Content-Type:text/plain;charset=utf-8";


// Sending message
$success = mail($subject, $emailbody, $header);

// Redirect after sending the message
if ($success){
print "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0;URL=de/confirmation_signup.html\">";
}
else{
print "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0;URL=de/error.html\">";
}
?>
```

Anybody has a clue what is going wrong inside the form?

Answer (score 0):

You are passing vars to mail function wrong;
Change this:

```
mail($subject, $emailbody, $header);
```

To this:

```
mail($to,$subject, $emailbody, $header);
```

See: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php

Comment: I fullfilled the mail function witch $to but it didn't work for me, no emails coming in. I can't find the problem. :(